# BigQuery - Query time becomes extremely long

Tags: google-bigquery

Recently all my query takes too long time but basically all of them consume no data.

For example, for a really simple query

```
Start Time: Jan 14, 2016, 12:35:13 PM
End Time: Jan 14, 2016, 12:35:15 PM
Bytes Processed: 0 B
Bytes Billed: 0 B
Billing Tier: 1
Destination Table: ****************.******************
Write Preference: Append to table
Allow Large Results: true
Flatten Results: true
```

this is the information I got from the BQ console, which tells me that this query doesn't consume any data(it's true) and only takes two seconds.

But it actually takes 27 seconds when I run this query again in the console by click `Run Query` in the query history. And after that, the `Query History` in the console shows this query takes 2 seconds again.

Basically all the query in this dataset have this issue.

I have over 40000 tables in this dataset.

So my guess is that before the BQ actually run the query, it first locates the table that is gonna be used. Then it starts to execute the query, which here is the `start time` in the query history.

If that is the case, how should I solve it and why does it take so long?

Here is the query I mentioned(have made some changes):

```
select "some_id", '2015-12-01', if (count(user_id) == 0, NULL, sum(users_in_today_again) / count(user_id)) as retention
from
(
select
  users_in_last_day.user_id as user_id,
  if(users_in_today.user_id is null, 0, 1) as users_in_today_again
FROM
(
select user_id
from
  table_date_range(ds.sessions_some_id_, date_add(timestamp('2015-12-01'), -1, "DAY"), date_add(timestamp('2015-12-01'), -1, "DAY"))
group by user_id
) as users_in_last_day
left join
(
select user_id
from table_date_range(ds.sessions_some_id_, timestamp('2015-12-01'), timestamp('2015-12-01'))
group by user_id
) as users_in_today
on users_in_last_day.user_id = users_in_today.user_id
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yikes! That's a pretty nasty query. If you are doing something this complex, I'd strongly advise issuing queries programmatically and basically doing a sequence of queries where you take the output of one query to generate the next query programmatically. Among the issues here, I think your mentioning of "count(user_id)" may be causing the entire table to be iterated on each record to count up the number of users. Try issuing the count query separately, first, and then referencing its value later in a followup pass.

Comment: (Cloud Dataflow may be another alternative to using BigQuery here).

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan Thanks for respond. I don't think the number of row processed is the cause of this issue. As I mentioned, this query didn't process any data. The table sessions_some_id_20151201 is empty. And I tried to remove the `count(user_id)` from the top  as you suggest, the time didn't change.

Answer (score 3):

```
PART 1
```

You can check your theory about delay before start time by using [Jobs:Get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get) API with the jobid taken from Query History in BQ Console.
As you can see in [Job Resources](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#resource) - `statistics` parameter in addition to `startTime` and `endTime` has also has also `creationTime`

```
PART 2
```

Shooting in the dark here, but try below

```
SELECT "some_id", '2015-12-01', IF (COUNT(user_id) == 0, NULL, SUM(users_in_today_again) / COUNT(user_id)) AS retention
FROM
(
  SELECT
    users_in_last_day.user_id AS user_id,
    IF(users_in_today.user_id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS users_in_today_again
  FROM
  (
    SELECT user_id FROM (
      SELECT user_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id) AS pos
      FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(ds.sessions_some_id_, DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP('2015-12-01'), -1, "DAY"), DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP('2015-12-01'), -1, "DAY"))
    ) WHERE pos = 1
  ) AS users_in_last_day
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT user_id FROM (
      SELECT user_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id) AS pos
      FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(ds.sessions_some_id_, TIMESTAMP('2015-12-01'), TIMESTAMP('2015-12-01'))
    ) WHERE pos = 1
  ) AS users_in_today
  ON users_in_last_day.user_id = users_in_today.user_id 
)
```

I know, it might look silly, but explanation stats (based on some dummy data) for this version 
[image]
is totally different from same for version in question
[image]

My wild guess is that heavy read/compute Stage1/2 in original version can be responsible for the delay in question

Just guess

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are right. I tried to run the query and checked the `creationTime`, `startTime` and the `endTime`. The delay between creationTime and the `startTime` is 25 seconds, while that between `startTime` and `endTime` is nearly 0 seconds. Any idea why the first delay is so big?

Comment: So, first part of your question was relatively easy. For second part, think what else you can provide to help answering it

Comment: added Part 2 to my answer

Comment: Thanks for the update! That was great! It is a good point to change the `group` to a combination of `partition` and `where`. But problem is my `ds.sessions_some_id_20151201` is empty. That's the very reason I think the delay is caused by table locating. I just ran another experiment by copying the `ds.sessions_some_id_20151201` and `ds.sessions_some_id_20151130` (two empty tables) to another empty dataset, when I run this query there, it took less than one second.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted at on the comment thread on Mikhail's question, most of the time is probably spent evaluating the `TABLE_DATE_RANGE` functions in the query.  This time is currently accounted for between `creationTime` and `startTime` in query statistics.

In general, tens or hundreds of thousands of tables in a dataset will cause slow performance when using `TABLE_DATE_RANGE`, `TABLE_QUERY`, or the `<dataset>.__TABLES__` metatable.  We are working to update our public documentation to mention this.

My suggestion is that if you want to use table wildcards on a dataset, make sure it doesn't have too many tables in it.  If that solution is unworkable for you, let us know if BigQuery could support something that would make your use case easier on our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/).